# unable to print to Linux network printer access denied

Tags: networking, permissions, lubuntu, printing, samba

I have Lubuntu 16.04 on my desktop pc, an HP deskjet 1050-j410 printer connected by USB.The printer works fine directly from my desktop. I have CUPS & SAMBA installed. It is shared & visible on the network.  I am unable to print to the Linux network printer from my Vista laptop,I get an "access denied" error. During installation to the laptop it will print a test page but nothing after that.

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the [global] stanza of smb.conf and see if it goes away:

```
use client driver = yes
```